SQL query hangs when trying to run any R code
So I am trying to run some R code as part of a SQL query, but it hangs no matter what I put in the R script.
See the below screenshot as an example (this script should list installed R packages, as described here):

Here's that query as text should you want to copy and paste it:
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'
OutputDataSet <- data.frame(installed.packages()[,c("Package", "Version", "Depends", "License", "LibPath")]);'
WITH result sets((
            Package NVARCHAR(255)
            , Version NVARCHAR(100)
            , Depends NVARCHAR(4000)
            , License NVARCHAR(1000)
            , LibPath NVARCHAR(2000)
            ));

Or even if I leave the script part as empty the same thing happens:

The server is an Azure SQL Managed Instance, general purpose tier, standard-series (Gen 5)
I've tried various scripts but it doesn't seem to matter what I put in there, it always hangs, so I assume it's something wrong with the setup

Please [edit] your post and copy your text-based code directly into body of question and not as screenshots. See Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Could you share any errors you are facing with?
